# Android - Store an image on device?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My application allows users to take a photo using the camera and save it as their profile picture. There can be only 1 image stored at a time?

- Is it a bad idea to use SharedPrefertences for this purpose although I am only storing 1 image?  (Converting image to Base64). What are the cons?
- If storing the image using shared preferences is not a good idea, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think storing binary data in SharedPreferences is not a good idea. Instead save it to the filesystem. Example for that, if the data is coming from an InputStream:

```
storeImage( new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + fileDir), 
            is, 
            "profile.png" ); 

public static void storeImage( 
            File fileDir, 
            InputStream inputStream, 
            String fileName ) throws IOException {
    File file = new File( fileDir,fileName );
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( file );
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    inputStream.close();
    fos.close();
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
}
```

Where context can be the Application/Activity context.

Comment: What about the easy background work that [apply](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) provides? "You don't need to worry about Android component lifecycles and their interaction with apply() writing to disk. The framework makes sure in-flight disk writes from apply() complete before switching states." When you drop to the file-system level, you either block your main application thread of deal with threading yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you can't use `SharedPreferences` to store a single image as a Base64 String,  Of course this isn't really a scalable approach as when the `SharedPreferences` are loaded, every image would be loaded into memory at once, but that's not what your looking for.

The other possible approaches you can take is to store the images either using the [internal](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) or [external](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) storage APIs or to store them in a [database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

In general for this kind of thing you should be looking to use something other than shared preferences, however in this case, I can't see there been an actual issue to the approach your suggesting.